# Запрет прокрутки тела при position:fixed на mobile safari

Tags: css, прокрутка, safari

Есть самый обычный вызов фиксированного элемента, и проблема в том что ничто пока не устранило нежелательную прокрутку `body` при открытом окне (а я перепробовал и перекопал весь англоязычный стак (хоть решения с библиотеками я и не пробовал)), еще проблема в том что когда ты листаешь уже сами секции в некоторых местах прокрутка с активного ныне окна просто проваливается на `body` и скроллит опять же его. Подскажите как корректно и малой кровью это можно решить?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/RwoOZbj)

```css
.block-anim .fix-wrapper { 
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.block-anim {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

section {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
```